# How can I reduce memory size without using diff xml file for each item in android?

Tags: android, xml, recipe

I am working with android app.Since I am new to android development, I completed my recipe app using diff XML file. I used each XML page for each item and it can be selected using the list activity. But it seems to be large memory size . How can I reduce this memory ?? Or is there any other method  without using diff XML for each one ??? please help me and thanks

Comment: whats the present size of app?

Comment: above 20 mb for the generated apk file :( how can i reduce this ?? is it any way to reduce the number of xml file ?? ie, can content to store to a single one ?? is it posible ??? if yes , kindly explain please

Comment: are you using any video files or images files..

Comment: i used  images an text only for the xml pages

Comment: [Hope this help you.][1]
check this question

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815269/how-to-reduce-app-apk-size

Answer (score 1):

you can define all view at runtime..

so it will consume memory.

Comment: how can i do this?? please explain I am in just learning stage of android

Comment: go this links [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763366/how-to-create-multiple-buttons-at-runtime-android)

Comment: go this links [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763366/how-to-create-multiple-buttons-at-runtime-android)

`[this]`(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693744/android-runtime-layout-tutorial)

`[this]`(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583019/dynamic-textview-in-relative-layout)

`[this]`(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261811/dynamically-adding-linearlayouts-in-android)

`[this]`(stackoverflow.com/questions/7354034/dynamically-add-a-textview-android)

`[This]`(stackoverflow.com/questions/9509842/how-to-add-a-dynamically-created-linearlayout-to-a-scrollview)

Answer (score 0):

you can make all the views at the run time. and if some activities has same layouts you can use one layout for all that activities.

Try to generate all the layouts values dynamically. It will reduce size as well as helps to maintain the app for future updates.

Comment: I am trying to load images from drawable to the same imageview for diff  actions .is it posiible ?? show me an example if you dont mind thank you

Comment: You please put some code as an sample of what you are actually doing.
If will be a good way to help you out in this